# Sorting using SimpleAdapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to sort my `Listview` according to some value in my application but i dont know how to code it. I researched and found that people are using comparator and collection to sort the arraylist. Basically, i want to sort by some status such as accepted or rejected. The value is store in `TAG_ACCEPT_REJECT` and display in `R.id.applicantStatus`.

**Below is my code:**

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ApplicantJobStatusActivity.this,
                applicantsList,
                R.layout.list_applicant_status,
                new String[] { TAG_UID, TAG_NAME,
                               TAG_ACCEPT_REJECT,
                               TAG_ACCEPT_REJECT_DATETIME },
                new int[] { R.id.applicantUid,
                            R.id.applicantName,
                            R.id.applicantStatus,
                            R.id.accept_reject_datetime });
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I want to know how and where to place the sorting code using comparator and collection to rearrange my `ListView`.

Answer (score 3):

You should sort your list `applicantsList` prior to passing it to your adapter. You can then use the `Collections.sort` approach. Something like that:

```
Collections.sort(applicantsList, new Comparator<T extends Map<String, ?>> {
  public int compare(T map1, T map2) {
    if (!map1.has(TAG_ACCEPT_REJECT)) return -1;
    if (!map2.has(TAG_ACCEPT_REJECT)) return 1;

    // Assumes the objects you store in the map are comparables
    return map1.get(TAG_ACCEPT_REJECT).compareTo(map2.get(TAG_ACCEPT_REJECT));
  }
});
```

Comment: Use this to sort the array used to initialize your SimpleArrayAdapter and you're set to go. Also, you might wanna re-write your ArrayAdapter to implement auto-sorting on every dataSetChanged() or getView()

Comment: where do i place this Collections.sort() code in? Inside the onCreate method?

Comment: From my answer: "You should sort your list applicantsList prior to passing it to your adapter.". So before `adapter = new SimpleAdapter(` seems like a good place.

Comment: But i am using a droplist to sort by choice. for e.g. sort by a-z or z-a etc

Answer (score 1):

**-** Use `Arrays.sort()` **before** assigning the `Array` to the `Adapter`.

**-** Or you can Use `Collections.sort(Collection c)` with `Comparable` Interface,

**-** Or `Collections.sort(Collection c, Comparator cp)` with `Comparator Interface, with Colletions like` ArrayList`before assigning it to the`Adapter`.

**///////////////////////// Edited Part//////////////////////////**

See this below link, which contains all the examples of **sorting an Array, ArrayList etc using various techniques.**

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/